# Does there exist a function which is real-valued, non-negative and bandlimited?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

There are obviously real-valued functions $f$ which are bandlimited. Take, for instance, $f = \mathrm{sinc}$. Can $f$ be also non-negative at the same time?

Comment: The absolute value of the sine cardinal, for instance.

Comment: In my opinion, you should define "bandlimited". Do you mean, for instance, that the Fourier transform has compact support?

Comment: Yes, exactly. With bandlimited I mean that the Fourier transform of $f$ has support in a compact interval $[-r,r]$ where $0<r<\infty$

Comment: Take $\sin(x) +1$ or $sinc(x) + 50$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any real $L^{2}$ function $g$ which is bandlimited. Then $\hat g *\hat g$ has compact support and this is the Fourier transform of $h^{2}$  where $h(x)=g(-x)$.